# Why can't i see the textfile that i've created in the working directory?

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception

```
File f = new File("textfile.txt");
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

This prints out the path of the textfile, but when i go to it's directory the textfile is not there. Is the textfile hidden or not created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because, you didn't create a file, you created a `File`.

`File` represents a virtual/abstract *filename*. It doesn't need to actually exist on the disk.

While there is a few ways to do this, the simplest might be to use [`File#createNewFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()), just make sure you check the return value, as it's not gurenteed to work

```
File file = new File("textfile.txt");
System.out.println("Exists: " + f.exists());
if (!file.exists()) {
    if (!file.createNewFile()) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, could not create " + file);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Create file " + file + " successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: But the last time i used new File("textfile.txt"); , the textfile actually appears.

Comment: @kevinlee Then I would suggest that either the file already existed or you wrote to the file in some way.

Comment: I have another question. Do i need to change the directory path to somewhere else? and how can i change the root directory setting? I'm using netbeans ide to save and retrieve data

Comment: @kevinlee You can find a fairly comprehensive tutorial on working with files at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html

Comment: Creating a `File` object without providing a path will place the file within in the current execution context of the program (the working directory).  To change the path, you either need to supply a relative path or absolute path to the location you want the file. Beware though, some OS's make actively restrict access to the root path context. Under Windows you can use `/textfile.txt` to get to the root of the current drive, for example...also beware, that if the path does not exist, calling `createNewFile` will fail, as it will not create the path for you...

Comment: Regarding the createNewFile, it returns true if the named file does not exist and was successfully created; false if the named file already exists. What if it fails to create the file due to incorrect path? will it return false?

Comment: @kevinlee `false`.  You can use something like `if (file.getParentFile().exists() || file.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {...}` to check to see if the path exists AND try and make the directories...